# Import Range Query not importing data

Tags: google-sheets

Sorry I know this question has been asked before - I have tried changing my query around but can't seem to get it to work as expected, doesn't look to be anything wrong..

I am simply trying to query data from one large master sheet into a few separate sheets. I am using importrange to get the data from sheet, and a simple select query to filter by one of the columns. If I do a select * I get all the data as expected, but can't use a WHERE clause with any column (I just need 1 of the columns, but I tried with a few different ones).

Appreciate any help!

Query:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1sNA9u2uQW-XjEKjrVS2a5LtTPCchwSuTkXfjhTJtvPk","Sheet1!B:I"),"select * WHERE 'Rank'='LTC' ")
```

Columns

```
Username    Rank    Time In Service     TIS Time In Grade   TIG Promotable  Awards  PLT/SQD
```

Source sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sNA9u2uQW-XjEKjrVS2a5LtTPCchwSuTkXfjhTJtvPk

Test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UCucsfE0M4j95d_47iN0LrAhS0luv8wXVMHRVTHJHRQ

Comment: sheets are private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As player0 stated, you should refer to the columns by its number, you can select multiple columns and state multiple "where" statements by using Col1,Col2, etc respectively. In this case: Where Col2 = 'LTZ'

Comment: Thanks, I thought those were just placeholders while looking at tutorials!

Comment: actually no coz range is B:I so Col1 is B

Comment: You're right, thought it was the names of columns since B and not since A

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1sNA9u2uQW-XjEKjrVS2a5LtTPCchwSuTkXfjhTJtvPk", "Sheet1!B:I")},
 "where Col1='LTC' ", )
```

Comment: Thanks, this did it! Thought the Col# were just placeholders..